# EditText Password toggle button not showing password

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, android-support-library

I am using support library `com.android.support:design:27.0.2` and I implemented password toggle inside `EditText`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/primary_dark"
            android:id="@+id/edit_inputPassword"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/primary_dark"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/edit_editPassword"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I got this password box after above code
[image: Toggle Password]

But when I clicked on Toggle button (Eye button) its doesn't show the password `String`.

Comment: is this your full layout ? can you post the full layout ? and one more thing is your `Api Level` above 21 ?

Comment: @SantanuSur min api 15,compile in 26. That's the layout of particular edit text

Comment: in which phone did you test ?? and also change the compileSdkVersion to 27 as you are using 27.0.2

Comment: sorry my mistake compile SDK is 27. I am testing it on Nexus 5 which has android 6 Marshmallow (API 23)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` instead of just `EditText`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/primary_dark"
            android:id="@+id/edit_inputPassword"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/primary_dark"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/edit_editPassword"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```